# Common practice to pass class names to views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dry

I have a controller method that passes model names and class names to a view. These classes are then instantiated in another controller method. In this case I'm using the Laravel Excel package.

```
public function index()
{
    $exports = [
        'Model name 1' => TestExport::class,
        'Model name 2' => AnotherExport::class
    ];

    return view('export', compact('exports'));
}


public function download(string $collection)
{
    return Excel::download(new $collection(), 'Export.xlsx');
}
```

My view file then redirects to the `download` controller method with the specific class name.

```
@foreach($exports as $name => $collection)
  <a href="{{ action('ExportController@download', $collection) }}">Download</a>
@endforeach
```

Since I'm learning design patterns, and noticed it would break the DRY rule, I didn't want another controller method or every different Excel file that I downloaded.

Is this good practice or can this be done better?

Comment: _Might_ be better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `$exports` common to both method and not accept class name from the request.

```
const EXPORTS = [
        'export_name_1' => TestExport::class,
        'export_name_2' => AnotherExport::class,
    ];
public function index()
{
    return view('export', compact(self::EXPORTS));
}


public function download(string $collection)
{
    if (!isset(self::EXPORTS[$collection]) {
        return 'error';
    }
    $className = self::EXPORTS[$collection];
    return Excel::download(new $className(), 'Export.xlsx');
}
```

Never let request manipulation break your code. For the `export_name`, you can simply use integers or the array simple index.

**View**

```
@foreach($exports as $name => $collection)
  <a href="{{ action('ExportController@download', $name)}}">Download</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Looking sharp! What if I wanted custom names and/or filenames in my view for each class name?

Comment: @Bas well, you can move the `const` to a config file (for example `config/exports.php`) and add all the info by export in it. The exports will still be independent from any method

Answer (score 0):

To me it feels like your solution is mixing view logic with controller logic.

- A controller should handle an incoming request, fetch the right data and then form a response.
- A view should handle any logic based on the given data in order to render the output page.

In your case the data you pass to the view is not retrieved, it's just a static list which could be kept in the view just as well. A better solution would be to either:

1. Have a list of routes (not a list of classes) in your blade template and iterate over that instead.
2. If the list of routes is not that long, hardcode the whole list instead of making it dynamic.

The main reason for doing so would be to prevent a lot of 'magic' code. For instance in your blade template you expect `exports` to be an array which contains a list of classes which HAVE to be controllers and which HAVE to have a `download` function otherwise the code breaks.

An example for solution 1 would look something like:

```
<?php
 // You could consider moving $routes to the controller
$routes = [
    action('ExportController@download', TestExport::class),
    action('ExportController@download', AnotherExport::class),
];

@foreach($routes as $route)
    <a href="{{ $route }}">Download</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you provide me with a code example? Wouldn't the list of routes end in more then one `download` controller method?